# How can I check price of each sub class?

Tags: c++, vector

```
class Attraction {

};

class Museum : public Attraction {
private:
    double price;

public:
    void setPrice(double Price) {
        price = Price;
    }

    double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
};

class Park : public Attraction {

public:
    double getPrice() {
        return 0;
    }

};

class Theatre : public Attraction {
private:
    double price;

public:
    void setPrice(double Price) {
        price = Price;
    }

    double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    vector<Attraction> attraction;

    vector<Attraction>::iterator i;

    for (i = attraction.begin(); i != attraction.end(); i++) {

        if (i->getPrice() < 5) {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't with the way you have designed it. `Attraction` does not have a `getPrice` method

Comment: @khredos: that's not the main issue (you could theoretically have a static visitor), it's slicing that kills this.

Comment: The short answer is -- not at all like this. But the "right way" depends on the specifics of your use case. You might want a vector of `unique_ptr`s, you might wants `ptr_vector`. You might want something else entirely. For example, what semantics do you want if the collection is coped?

Answer (score 2):

`vector<Attraction>` performs object slicing, so you can never access `getPrice()` of derived classes. You need to use polymorphism instead, where you have a virtual `double GetPrice()` method in the `Attraction` class, and then use `vector<Attraction*>` with `new`/`delete` for the objects.  Don't forget to make the destructor in `Attraction` virtual as well, so you can `delete` descendant object using a base pointer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are attempting to do is not possible with the code you have shown.  You are not utilizing polymorphism correctly.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class Attraction
{
public:
    Attraction() {}
    virtual ~Attraction() {}

    virtual double getPrice(double Price)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
};

class PriceyAttraction : public Attraction
{
private:
    double price;

public
    PriceyAttraction(double Price = 0.0) : Attraction(), price(Price) {}

    virtual double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    void setPrice(double Price)
    {
        price = Price;
    }
};

class Museum : public PriceyAttraction
{
public:
    Museum(double Price = 0.0) : PriceyAttraction(Price) {}
};

class Park : public Attraction
{
public:
    Park() : Attraction() {}
};

class Theatre : public PriceyAttraction
{
public:
    Theatre(double Price = 0.0) : PriceyAttraction(Price) {}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<Attraction*> attraction;

    attraction.push_back(new Museum(5.00));
    attraction.push_back(new Park);
    attraction.push_back(new Theatre(7.50));

    std::vector<Attraction*>::iterator i;
    for (i = attraction.begin(); i != attraction.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i->getPrice() << std::endl;
        //...
    }

    for (i = attraction.begin(); i != attraction.end(); ++i)
    {
        delete *i;
    }
}
```

If you are using C++11 or later, you can use `std::unique_ptr` to manage the object deallocations for you:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Attraction>> attraction;

    attraction.emplace_back(new Museum(5.00));
    attraction.emplace_back(new Park);
    attraction.emplace_back(new Theatre(7.50));
    /* or:
    attraction.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Attraction>(new Museum(5.00)));
    attraction.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Attraction>(new Park));
    attraction.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Attraction>(new Theatre(7.50)));
    */
    /* or:
    attraction.push_back(std::make_unique<Museum>(5.00));
    attraction.push_back(std::make_unique<Park>());
    attraction.push_back(std::make_unique<Theatre>(7.50));
    */

    vector<Attraction>::iterator i;
    for (i = attraction.begin(); i != attraction.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << (*i)->getPrice() << std::endl;
        //...
    }
}
```